# Choice of data types when passing a Table Valued Parameter (TVP) from C# to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado

Problem: documentation for [`System.Data.DataColumn.DataType Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx) lists a paltry selection of datatypes and adds that it's possible to define a column as a different data type:

> Although it is possible to define a column as data type other than the base .NET Framework data types and Byte[], such a column will be treated as a user-defined type, subject to the following usage restrictions (for more information on user-defined types, see *Creating and Using User-Defined Types*).

I can't seem to find this *Creating and Using User-Defined Types* documentation. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Please note, I'm not looking for a work around or advice on how to deal with this limitation. Just want to find how MS wants us to define custom data types in datatables.

For reference, a similar question: [SQL Geometry Type can't be used in System.data.datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413490/datatable-containing-sqlgeometry-is-causing-stored-procedure-execution-to-fail)

Comment: Though this question is off-topic to stackoverflow I have found your missing link. If you would go to the [official new documentation of the DataType property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_DataColumn_DataType) the link there goes to [Creating and Using User-Defined Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ec0266d2-7e5b-47e4-938a-85ac9d04fa40) in MSDN.

Comment: Thanks @ZoharPeled why off-topic?

Comment: From the close->off-topic reasons: "Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it."